# Git - revert significant changes

Tags: git

My local repository was on git "Branch A" and had a number of untracked files, so what I did is created a new branch (let's call it "Branch B"), switched to that branch added those files to commit and pushed it to remote repo.

What I want to do now is to revert everything back, namely, make the files from last commit untracked again, switch to "Branch A" and delete "Branch B" completely on local and remote.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout to `branchB` and undo the last committed files/changes by `soft reset` (keep the changes in working tree).

```
$ git checkout branchB
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1         # undo last commit
$ git status                      # see the undo changes
```

Unstage the files (pull files out of the index).

```
$ git reset

Or,
$ git rm --cached <file1> <file2>
```

Checkout to `branchA`.

```
$ git checkout branchA
$ git status                  # see the changes exists here also
```

Delete local and remote `branchB`.

```
$ git branch -D branchB      # delete local branch
$ git push origin :branchB   # delete remote branch
```

Comment: This is close, but not quite right: the `--soft` reset will leave added files added (see my example with file `U`). You would have to do some more `git reset` or `git rm --cached` operations to pull them out of the index.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. As I understand hard reset would do the unstaging as well in one command

Comment: `hard reset` is dangerous cause it would remove all the changes of undo's commit permanently!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the branch names is trivial.  The hard part is dealing with the index and changing branch names without disturbing the work-tree.  To do that, you want `git reset` and then `git checkout`, in a slightly tricky ordering.  This should be the right recipe (it assumes you are on `branch_B` right now):

```
git reset branch_A
git checkout branch_A
git push --delete origin branch_B
git branch -d branch_B
```

#### Explanation

To be clear here, there are *three* sets of active files at any one time:

- The current commit, which is read-only.  There is a read-only copy of every committed file.  There may be many branch names for this commit; the one of interest is `HEAD`.
- Everything in the *index* (aka *staging area* aka *cache*), which is read/write, but hard to see.
- Everything in the *work tree*, which you can just view with your normal viewer.  This includes both *tracked* files—files whose name is in the index—and *untracked* files, which are not in the index.

When you added everything, you copied some set of untracked files into the index, so that now the index had them too.  The index version and the work-tree version of each of those files would match (except perhaps for end-of-line CRLF type things, which we'll ignore).

There's a minor complication here: `git add .` or similar *doesn't* add things that are both untracked *and* marked for ignore.  So those files would not have been copied into the index.

Whenever you make a new commit, Git takes whatever is in your index right now and puts that in the new commit as its snapshot.  The new commit's *parent* commit is the commit that was current before.  The new commit becomes the current commit, by moving whichever branch is `HEAD`.  So, you started with this:

```
...--o--o--C1   <-- branch_A (HEAD)
             \
              [uncommitted things in index and work-tree]
```

You then created a new branch B:

```
...--o--o--C1   <-- branch_A, branch_B (HEAD)
             \
              [uncommitted things in index and work-tree]
```

Then you did `git add`, which copied some previously-untracked files into the index, and did `git commit`, which made a new commit `C2`:

```
...--o--o--C1   <-- branch_A
             \
              C2   <-- branch_B (HEAD)
                \
                [things in index: they match C2]
                  \
                  [any remaining untracked-and-ignored files]
```

Now, the problem is that when you back up to commit `C1`, Git will normally *remove* from your index and work-tree, any files that are committed in `C2` but are missing in `C1`.  It will reset, in your index and work-tree, files that are in both but are *different* in `C1`.

Let's say, for instance, that you had file `U` that had been untracked, but got added and committed into `C2`.  You also had file `T` that was already in `C1` and is also in `C2` but has different contents in `C2` than in `C1`.

You need to get into a state where `U` is again in your work-tree but *untracked*, and this is slightly tricky.

What you want is a *mixed* reset: make your current commit *be* `C1` and make your index match the *state* stored in `C1` without touching the work-tree at all.  This is what you get with `git reset --mixed`, which is the default.

The `git reset` operation *also* moves the current, i.e. `HEAD`, branch, to point to the new commit.  So we now do `git reset branch_A` to point the current branch, `branch_B`, to commit `C1`, and to make the index match that of `C1`.  The work-tree remains undisturbed, and we now have tihs:

```
                 [undisturbed work-tree with untracked files etc]
                /
              [things in index: they match C1]
             /
...--o--o--C1   <-- branch_A, branch_B (head)
             \
              C2    abandoned
```

Because the index now matches `C1`, the file `U` that *was* untracked, but is committed inside `C2`, is now out of the index.  Because we used `--mixed` (default) `reset`, file `U` is still in the work-tree.  File `T` in the index matches that in `C1` but the copy of `T` in the work-tree matches that of `C2` and the current work-tree, as `T` in the work-tree is also undisturbed.

Now we have the problem that the *current* branch is `branch_B`.  We want it to be `branch_A`.  Note that `branch_B` and `branch_A` both refer to commit `C1`: this is exactly what we want, because now switching branches has *no* effect on index and work-tree.  So now we use `git checkout branch_A` to get `HEAD` to name `branch_A` instead of `branch_B`, without changing the current *commit* at all.

Now it's safe to delete `branch_B` locally.  We can `push --delete` it in the other repository at any time, but just before or just after the local delete is an especially good time.

Answer (score 0):

Delete remote B branch: `git push <remote> --delete <branch_name>`

Delete local B branch: `git branch -d <branch_name>`

Revert Branch A: `git revert HEAD~1` (if it was only 1 commit)